# How to add an input.bool to Supertrend indicator?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am working with the following code in pine-script:

```
indicator("Volatility Trend", overlay=true)

[supertrend, direction] = ta.supertrend(3, 10)
TrendVolatility = input.bool(false, "Trend Volatility")

bodyMiddle = plot((open + close) / 2,editable=false, display=display.none)

upTrend = plot(direction < 0 ? supertrend : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, 
style=plot.style_linebr, editable = false)

downTrend = plot( direction < 0 ? na : supertrend, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr, editable = false)

fill(bodyMiddle, upTrend, color.new(color.green, 90), fillgaps=false, editable = false)
fill(bodyMiddle, downTrend, color.new(color.red, 90), fillgaps=false, editable = false)
```

My Goal is to insert the input.bool into each plot code, as to be able to turn the entire indicator on and off in the input menu. My problem is it will not let me put the single input.bool into any of the plot equations with the supertrend function. Thank you for your help.

I Tried to insert the input.bool function into the plot functions but I cant find a way to do it. I was able to do this with a seperate Ema indicator I made.

Answer (score 0):

You just use your input variable as a condition to the `series` argument of the `plot()`.

So, it will plot only if your input variables is `true`, otherwise the `series` argument will have `na`.

```
upTrend = plot(TrendVolatility ? (direction < 0 ? supertrend : na) : na, "Up Trend", color = color.green, style=plot.style_linebr, editable = false)
downTrend = plot(TrendVolatility ? (direction < 0 ? na : supertrend) : na, "Down Trend", color = color.red, style=plot.style_linebr, editable = false)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `display` argument in a similar manner:

```
display = TrendVolatility ? display.all : display.none
```